# Creating shapes using nested loop

Tags: c++, loops

I want to create this shape using nested loop.

```
$****
*$***
**$**
***$*
****$
```

However with my codes,

```
int counter = 6;
for (row = 0; row <= counter; row ++)
{   
    cout << "$";
    for (column = 1; column <= row ; column++)
    {
    cout << "*";
    }
    cout << endl;       
}
```

the outcome is:

```
$*
$**
$***
$****
$*****
$******
```

How is to create $ in every loop and moving positions in each loop?

Comment: just check if the inner and outer loop indices are equal and print `$` otherwise print `*`. Do all `cout`s inside the inner loop. Also make both loops run the same number of iterations `for (column = 1; column <= row ; column++)` => `for (column = 1; column <= counter ; column++)`.

Comment: @Saramali, nope it is not homework. it is a question from reference book. I want to practice my nested loop.

Comment: *How is to create $ in every loop and moving positions in each loop?* -- The goal of programming homework assignments is if you have the aptitude to figure this out yourself, and not ask here to give you the answer.   Otherwise any programming problem you encounter, all you need is ask here and get an answer, and that is not the way you learn how to write programs.

Comment: @engkhsky -- *nope it is not homework. it is a question from reference book* -- That is homework, or homework you've given yourself.

Comment: They're obviously trying to learn. Got stuck. Asked a question. That's what this site is for. Don't bag someone out for wanting help.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, I did tried. Actually i try alot of ways. the one i show is only one of them, the closest I can get. I didn't want answer only, I need a explanation on how and why.

Comment: @PaulRooney, Thanks! I did it! I didn't know i can use if else for that.

Answer (score 1):

You are only varying the amount of "*" you print. To achieve what you want you can try something like this.

```
int count = 0;
while(count < 5){
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
         if(i == count){
              cout << "$";
         } else{
              cout << "*";
         }
    }
    cout << endl;
    count++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I did it without looking at ur answer, since someone said in comment about using if else.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the nested loop condition is incorrect in which it will only print values according to the row number. However, your values in each row will remain same.Only, the dollar sign will keep on moving. Also, try to make generic functions which will take an integer as an input for row count which is a very good approach. Here is the solution:

```
void createDollarStars(int counter)
{
    int row,column;

    for (row = 0; row < counter; row ++)
    {   
    for (column = 0; column < counter ; column++)
    {
        if(row == column) 
        {
           cout<<"$";
        }
        else
        {
           cout << "*";
        }
    }
        cout << endl;       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to print the '$' when the inner loop and outer loop count is same and in other cases print '*'. This code should work for you

```
int counter = 6;
for (row = 1; row <= counter; row ++)
{   
    for (column = 1; column <= counter; column++)
    {
        if((column  == row){
                cout << "$";
         } else{
                cout << "*";
        }
    }
    cout << endl;       
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you want

```
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
        if(i==j)
        cout<<"$";
        else cout<<"*";
    }
    cout<<"\n";
}
```